# Is it possible to run Puppeteer with Chrome version 83?

Tags: puppeteer, cypress

I am getting some error messags, which (I think) might be related to Puppeteer expecting a different Chrome version. Now I've tried to ensure that Puppeteer expects the correct version by running:

```
npm install puppeteer-core@chrome-83
```

But that leads to:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for puppeteer-core@chrome-83 
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting 
npm ERR! notarget a package version  that doesn't exist.
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am using Puppeteer version 3.1.0

Edit: the question comes from the following error message

```
Error: Could not find browser revision 756035
```

Comment: I don't see a chrome-83 here https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-core

Answer (score 0):

From my testing it seems the latest build of chrome available in puppeteer is `puppeteer-core@chrome-81`